# Is it feasible to have UUID as the primary key for custom entities?

Tags: 7, entities

When creating your own entities via the [Entity API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity), it is possible to get a UUID key via the [UUID module](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid).

However, it seems that the default set-up is to still have a “serial” (ie. auto-incrementing integer) as primary key.

This is not optimal; there's no need to have two surrogate keys for the same object.

Does anyone have experience in using UUIDs as the the (only) primary key? Can you do it without having Views and other modules puke?